# Trouble with java arithmetic

Tags: java, math

I am making a side scrolling shooter in java and I am trying to figure out the arithmetic behind knowing where bullet would impact on a wall. So far i have decided that using the slope intercept form would work, but when I transferred the code into java it gives me strange answers.

```
    double impactY = ((mouseY-player.yPos)/(mouseX-player.xPos) * (800 - player.xPos) + player.yPos);
                                     ^Slope^                         ^ x value for the wall.

    impactY = 580.0
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _strange answers_?

Comment: What are the declared types of these values? It affects how Java will calculate these values.

Comment: Well obviously the result of that equation is not 580, and i believe that all values are integers.

Comment: @SpectreNoname: It is not obvious that the result of the equation is 580, because you have not shown what the input values are.

Comment: This really needs more information. Preferably more code upon which to view possible error and possibly some output as you've seen it.

Answer (score 2):

Without your providing more information on your problem, my best guess is that you are running into 'integer division' when it is not what you want.

If`MouseY`, `palyer.yPos`, `mouseX`, & `player.xPos` are integers, the division `(mouseY-player.yPos)/(mouseX-player.xPos)` will be Integer division instead of real number division. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

What you need to do is cast either the numerator or denominator as a double/float before the division occurs:

`((double) mouseY-player.yPos)/(mouseX-player.xPos)`